# Are there any dangers of setting kext-dev-mode to 1?

Tags: macos, driver, kernel-extensions

I am trying to make a driver work on my OSX 10.11. A guide that I am following requires the execution of the following command:

```
sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1"
```

followed by:

```
sudo kextload [path to driver of device]
```

There are some warning, however, on the internet about setting kext-dev-mode to 1.

What are the risks of doing so? Can I maybe run the second command and then set the kext-dev-mode to 0? Is it possible that the driver will work in that case?